# How to prevent log spam "Try to connect to the server ....................................error : 2Connection failed"

Tags: dll, windows-10, unreal-engine4

I'm getting >1Hz debug log spam while I'm attached to a process of the following text:

> Try to connect to the server ....................................error : 2Connection failed
>
> Try to connect to the server ....................................error : 231Connection failed
>
> Disconnection of the client .........................................

This text does not appear in any source file on my computer, and I could find no reference to it online. Where is this coming from, and how can I squelch it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message is being generated by nahimicOSD.dll, which appears to get installed alongside realtek audio drivers. The issue should be resolved by opening the services menu (Windows Key+R -> services.msc -> OK), right-click Nahimic service -> Properties -> General -> Startup type: Disabled, and rebooting the machine.

Found the offending dll by creating a breakpoint on OutputDebugStringW in Visual Studio 2019:
Debug -> New Breakpoint -> Function Breakpoint... -> Function Name: OutputDebugStringW

Checking the call stack indicates the culprit is nahimicOSD.dll, which appears to do nothing of value anyway (modern software, ladies and gentlemen).